# "Window Decals" - Make them "moveable"

Tags: car

Everyone is familiar with these kinds of decals that go on the inside of your car windows. Yearly park decals. Work decals. Parking lot decals. etc.

[image]

What "tricks" are there to be able to use these without making them permanent? I want something that can accept one of these and then "static cling?" to the window so I can move it between my two vehicles...

Comment: For the two "window decals" you have pictured, that is illegal.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman I'll find a different picture... that's just a random picture found out in the wild wild interwebs. It's the general idea I'm interested in, not legality - which will vary depending on what you get, where you get it, etc

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution: http://www.amazon.com/Parking-Permit-Holder-Sticky-Windshield/dp/B00DAE8O60

Comment: As well as this: http://www.amazon.com/STICKER-SHIELD-Windshield-Application-Re-application/dp/B01466E0GS

Answer (score 3):

A covering over the sticker's adhesive surface *(trimmed to fit)* with clear double sided tape would probably work well.

I expect that the adhesive from the sticker would likely bond with the adhesive on the tape to form a stronger bond than the bond formed between the glass and only the tape's adhesive.

Thus, enabling you to easily remove the sticker while retain the adhesiveness of the sticker without obscuring it, and without drawing additional attention to it.

[image: Clear double-sided tape]

> **Note:** There are multiple levels of adhesiveness available for double sided tape, so you may need to experiment in order to find the ideal option.
>
> For example, the image above displays a product billed as *Removable Double Sided Tape*.

Comment: I like that idea... You could, if careful, use multiple layers of clear tape that would conceivably survive multiple/consistent moves...

Answer (score 0):

Just get a piece of cardboard or a box or something like it and stick the decal to it, cut it to size if needed and only put it behind the windshield when needed. 
You might even take a brick.. so it cannot be blown away by wind.

There are also sucktion clips and sticky clips:

- https://dutch.alibaba.com/photo-products/parking-permit-holder-photos.html
- http://www.relatiegeschenk4you.nl/Files/2/40000/40337/ProductPhotos/Large/74634469.jpg

Enough possibilities! Good luck